# WindowsApps folder - how to get full access to paste and rename files

Tags: uwp, file-permissions

I want to rename a file in UWP application folder under %PF%\WindowsApps.

I made the current user the owner of the WindowsApps directory. I removed attribute inheritance for this directory. I gave full access to the directory and its subdirectories to both the current user and for everyone. I checked effective access rights - everything is allowed for the file that I want to rename. But when I try to rename it, the system first asks for an access rights elevation, after that it says that there are not enough rights to rename file.

Also, I can remove a file, but I can't copy a new file to that folder.

I started CMD in administrator mode, and do next commands:

```
>rem Backup current permissions
>icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /save WindowsApps.acl
>rem Take ownership
>takeown /F "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps"
>rem For sub folders and files
>takeown /F "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /r /d y
>rem Assign Full Control permissions to the folder
>icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /grant Administrators:F
>rem For its sub folders and files
>icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /grant Administrators:F /t
>rem remove Readonly attr
>attrib -R /S /D "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps"
>rem Rename DLL
>ren "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\SomeApp\sqlite3_org.dll" "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\SomeApp\sqlite3_org.dll"
Access denied
```

I can't understand what else is needed to rename file.

Comment: Could you please share some code snippets and detailed steps to help us understand the problem?